# Pydantic enum field does not get converted to string

Tags: python, serialization, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to restrict one field in a class to an enum. However, when I try to get a dictionary out of class, it doesn't get converted to string. Instead it retains the enum. I checked [pydantic documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#enums-and-choices), but couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.

This code is representative of what I actually need.

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel

class S(str, Enum):
    am = 'am'
    pm = 'pm'

class K(BaseModel):
    k: S
    z: str

a = K(k='am', z='rrrr')
print(a.dict()) # {'k': <S.am: 'am'>, 'z': 'rrrr'}
```

I'm trying to get the `.dict()` method to return `{'k': 'am', 'z': 'rrrr'}`

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You need to use `use_enum_values` option of [model config](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/):

> `use_enum_values`
>
> whether to populate models with the `value` property of enums, rather than the raw enum. This may be useful if you want to serialise `model.dict()` later (default: `False`)

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel

class S(str, Enum):
    am='am'
    pm='pm'

class K(BaseModel):
    k:S
    z:str

    class Config:  
        use_enum_values = True  # <--

a = K(k='am', z='rrrr')
print(a.dict())
```

Comment: is there a reason that this option is False by default? I feel in most of the cases we would require that to be true.

Comment: @Krishna one could argue why not leave dates as ISO8601 strings? Principle of least surprise is that you get what you ask for, you asked for an Enum

Comment: Is there a way to use the enum values when serializing using .dict() but keep the full enum when deserializing and constructing the pydantic object ?

Comment: I was wondering the same as @vianmixt. The whole reason why anyone would use an enum is so that when working with the object, one has the convenience that enums offer, but yet it can be serialized as a string as this is the simplest way to be language independent.

Comment: @vianmixt See [y26805's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73697224) for a solution that relies on FastAPI.

Answer (score 11):

You can use FastAPI's [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/#using-the-jsonable_encoder):

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

class S(str, Enum):
    am = 'am'
    pm = 'pm'

class K(BaseModel):
    k: S
    z: str

a = K(k='am', z='rrrr')
print(jsonable_encoder(a)) # {'k': 'am', 'z': 'rrrr'}
```

Comment: This is nice because you can keep the full `Enum` when deserializing and constructing the Pydantic object.

Comment: This is my preferred way of doing this as you don't always want to loose the enum type when using `model_dump`, would be nicer to pass `use_enum_values` when calling `model_dump`. Using `model_dump_json` does not always work in our use case either.

Answer (score 10):

#### Pydantic 2.0

By default, Pydantic preserves the enum data type in its serialization. To override this behavior, specify [`use_enum_values`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.use_enum_values) in the model config.

```py
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class S(str, Enum):
    am = 'am'
    pm = 'pm'


class K(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(use_enum_values=True)

    k: S
    z: str

a = K(k='am', z='rrrr')
print(a.model_dump()) # {'k': 'am', 'z': 'rrrr'}
```

> Note: `model_config` is now an attribute of type `ConfigDict` (this is a breaking change from V1).

#### Neater: Specify config options as [model class kwargs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/model_config/)

Alternatively, you can populate directly in the class definition:

```py
class K(BaseModel, use_enum_values=True):
    k: S
    z: str
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the kwargss!

Comment: Calling `.model_dump(mode="json")` allows for being able to get a json-able dict when dumping the object while retaining the ability to construct and deserialize objects with the actual enum type.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by using `Config` class is correct but may not be necessary.
It may be inconvenient to repeatedly implement and could be redundant for some readers so I offer easier alternatives and a short explanation.

#### TL;DR

- For JSON serialization, no need to do anything. Using `(Str,Enum)` subclasses is enough without Config.
- For printable representational string/other feature, create a custom `StrEnum` class. This was [added in 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum) but since previous versions don't support it - I provide an example.

#### Example

```py
from enum import Enum

class StrEnum(str, Enum):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return str.__repr__(self.value)

class A(str, Enum):
    FOO = "foo"

class B(StrEnum):
    BAR= "bar"

class C(BaseModel):
    a: A = Field(...)
    b: B = Field(...)

print(C(a="foo", b="bar").dict())

import json

print(json.dumps(C(a="foo", b="bar").dict()))
```

Outputs:

```
{'a': <A.FOO: 'foo'>, 'b': 'bar'}
{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}
```

#### Explanation

Class `A` and `B` are of types `(str, Enum)` and `StrEnum`, respectively.
Both are JSON serializable; `StrEnum` also prints as a primitive string.