# How create dict from Pydantic (Enum)?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have some object with Pydantic's class.
I have to create dict from object.

```
from enum import Enum

from pydantic import BaseModel


class StatusId(Enum):
    ACTIVE: int = 1
    PASSIVE: int = 2


class Pamagite(BaseModel):
    status_id: StatusId = StatusId.ACTIVE
    another_field: str = "another_field"
```

If I try do like this:

```
pamagite = Pamagite().dict()
```

I will get

```
pamagite = {'status_id': <StatusId.ACTIVE: 1>, 'another_field': 'another_field'}
```

I expected that pamagite will be equally to

```
pamagite = {'status_id': 1, 'another_field': 'another_field'}
```

How I can do this?

Comment: instead of `status_id: StatusId = StatusId.ACTIVE` try `status_id: StatusId = StatusId.ACTIVE.value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pydantic enum field does not get converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209934/pydantic-enum-field-does-not-get-converted-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `use_enum_values = True` [option](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#options).

> whether to populate models with the value property of enums, rather than the raw enum. This may be useful if you want to serialise model.dict() later (default: False)

```
from enum import Enum

from pydantic import BaseModel


class StatusId(Enum):
    ACTIVE: int = 1
    PASSIVE: int = 2


class Pamagite(BaseModel):
    status_id: StatusId = StatusId.ACTIVE
    another_field: str = "another_field"

    class Config:
        use_enum_values = True


pamagite = Pamagite().dict()

print(pamagite)  # "{'status_id': 1, 'another_field': 'another_field'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

here,

```
class Pamagite(BaseModel):
    status_id: StatusId = StatusId.ACTIVE.value
    another_field: str = "another_field"
```

Calling the dict over the class object will give you

```
{'status_id': 1, 'another_field': 'another_field'}
```

Calling `StatusId.ACTIVE.value` will give you `1` and calling `StatusId.ACTIVE.name` will give you `ACTIVE` in case if you want to use `ACTIVE` instead of `1`